# Searching for a Web Element that appears in websites

Tags: python, selenium, classname

Good Day fellow coders, 
I'm curious if there is a way to query google to see if you can find websites that have a certain web element appear in them. For example, if there was a logo, that had a very specific class name, or id, can I query that against google to see who is rendering that logo? My initial research doesn't show too promising, but if anyone would know how to do it, it would be one or more of you guys.

Thank you in advance to one of the greatest communities that exists.

Comment: show some code please

Comment: This isn’t a question of code as much as it is query. If I’m able to identify the sites that render the web element I can iterate through them appropriately, but I’m having a hard time making a google query that’s based on source code

Comment: you have to scrape them, long story doenst help me